# Render Google Charts on server

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, google-visualization, png

In our web application we are using Google Charts. Now we have to create monthly reports as pdf, which should contain same (or very similar) Charts.

Is there a way to render Google Charts on the server side in .Net?

Edit:
What I basically need are line-charts with multiple lines and pie charts so nothing extraordinary. I am using C# and for pdf creating MigraDoc/PdfSharp, but we really don't like the look of the MigraDoc charts.

Comment: You could use something like PhantomJS on the server side.  It can capture a web page to a variety of image formats, including PDF:  http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html  ...but the PDF version may be fully rasterized, which wouldn't be great for printing, searching, etc.  Or Google Charts lets you get a PNG of a chart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

Comment: The png mentioned above is rendered client-side in JavaScript.  There's nothing to say this couldn't be done, but it's definitely not the way Google Charts is intended to be used.  As long as you can get it to run, you should be able to render the chart and capture it somehow, but it would need to be running in an environment that mimics a browser.  I know if nothing that can do this as a .Net solution, which would mean building a very complex solution to talk between .Net and your JavaScript runtime.  All this being said, there are other libraries for rendering charts on the server side.

Comment: If you can be more specific about the .Net technologies you are using, and the types of Google Charts you are currently rendering on the client, the Stack Overflow community may be able to suggest a server-side solution for you.